# Add items to sidemenu

Tags: android

I'm trying to add menuitem to a submenu but I do not get them added to the id item that I am going through.

What I add by code is created at the end but what I want is that it is added to the 'R.id.sidemenu_groups' sub-menu that I have created in XML.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/sidemenu_principal"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_user_contacts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Favoritos" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_team_contacts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Contactos de la empresa" />
    <!--<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Registro" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Favoritos" />-->
</group>

<item
    android:id="@+id/sidemenu_groups"
    android:title="Departamentos">
    <menu
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/add_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Add Item" />
    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="Ajustes">
    <menu android:id="@+id/sidemenu_other">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Ajustes" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

```
private void makeMenu() {
    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    final SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Departamentos");
    subMenu.add(R.id.sidemenu_groups, Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY, 0, "Menu3");
}
```

[Menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8BEB.png)

How can I add diferents items to R.id.sidemenu_groups?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake that you've done, just make sure you do like this and you'll be able to achieve what you wanna achieve. **And never forget to give different ids in order to add different things programmatically**

```
private void makeMenu() {
final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
//since you have called the navMenu object you don't have to go for any submenu
//this way you add the menu items
menu.add(R.id.sidemenu_groups, 1, 100, "Menu3");
menu.add(R.id.sidemenu_groups, 2, 200, "Menu4");
menu.add(R.id.sidemenu_groups, 3, 300, "Menu5");
//make sure to make this as single checkable and if you've set you navItem as invisible then do make it visible 
menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.sidemenu_groups, true, true);
menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.sidemenu_groups, true);  }
```

**EDITS**

Try adding this to your code and tell me if works

```
    MenuItem menu = 
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.sidemenu_groups);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.getSubMenu();
    //then try adding all the item like this
    subMenu.add("Menu3");
    subMenu.add("Menu4");
    subMenu.add("Menu5");
    //make sure to make this as single checkable and if you've set you 
    //navItem as invisible then do make it visible 
    menu.setGroupCheckable(R.id.sidemenu_groups, false, false);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.sidemenu_groups, true);  }
```

Happy Learning! Tell me if you face any problem in this.

Comment: Thanks but I need the three items inside this:
[code]<item android:title="Departamentos">
        <menu
            android:id="@+id/sidemenu_groups"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <!--- I need the items here -->
            <item
                android:id="@+id/add_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Add Item" />
        </menu>
    </item>

Comment: See the edits in my answer and try to implement and tell me whether you are getting the desired result

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is you can create your custom menu using recyclerView / ExpandableListView. This will give you more flexibility.

Comment: please post complete answer with proper explanation and reference links to your answer, and try to post the code ass well to propose a proper solution